# How to put label in row of form with align by right?

Tags: html, css

There is the following form:

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/news" class="new_news" id="new_news" method="post">
    <div class='row'>
      <label for="news_content">Content</label>
      <input id="news_content" name="news[content]" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <label for="news_subject">Subject</label>
      <input id="news_subject" name="news[subject]" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

I need to align label in row with the fixed length and text is aligned by right:

```
label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

But it doesn't do what I need. What's the mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't really get you. What's wrong with this? The text is aligned right. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/STvvf/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a design like

```
|___textbox_____| label
```

Then you should go with `float` property.

```
label {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
input[type="textbox"] {
    float: left;
}
form {
    width:230px;  //we need to add this to have closed view
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2PkqL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css

```
div
{
    clear:both;
}
```

to your divs, look to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPQjX/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that that they are asking for? I don't see how it is. They have given us limited CSS (label only) and that it is. They have `.row` already there so I'm pretty sure that does the whole layout for them.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a "[clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)" or you could add `display:inline-block` to your div with class "row".

See this [demo](http://jsbin.com/digom/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your div clear from left float. You can get it by using **clear:left** on div's. Checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tT8AX/

```
div
{
    clear:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do Float:right; in css

```
label {
float: right;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 15px;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.4em;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have aligned as 
[image]

Here is a jsFiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9JzC/)

CSS

```
label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;

}
.btnrow { 
    float:right;
    width:250px;

}
```

HTML

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/news" class="new_news" id="new_news" method="post">
    <div class='row'>
      <label for="news_content">Content</label>
      <input id="news_content" name="news[content]" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <label for="news_subject">Subject</label>
      <input id="news_subject" name="news[subject]" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='btnrow'>
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Добавить" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your "**row**" class contains. 
In case it does not have anything the you can check the styles which I have mentioned and that will fix your issue.

[Check this out here](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanibhanwal/KhAms/)

*CSS to fix the code*

```
.row{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.button{
  margin-left: 115px;
}

label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I have added extra div,

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/news" class="new_news" id="new_news" method="post">
    <div class='row'>
      <span class="lable_class"><label for="news_content">Content</label></span>
      <span class="input_class"><input id="news_content" name="news[content]" type="text" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <span class="lable_class"><label for="news_subject">Age</label></span>
      <span class="input_class"><input id="news_subject" name="news[subject]" type="text" /></span>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Click" />
    </div>
  </form>
 <div>
```

and few css modifications and additions,

```
.lable_class {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
.input_class{
    width: 300px;
}
.row{
    margin-right: 175px;
    text-align: right;
}
.wrapper{
    padding-top:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use float if you want to align it whether left or right.

```
label {
float: right;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 15px;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 5px;
font-size: 1.4em;
}
```